# What font is "z" in "z-score"?

Tags: fonts, statistics

[image]

I noticed that the letter z is different from other font. Is there any special command for this?

Comment: italic z in Times-like fonts, such as `mathptmx`.

Comment: It's just how a font realizes the italic z. Nothing special about *z*-score.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Times font in both cases.  The difference is italic versus upright.  Kerning is slightly different if employed as math versus italic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$z$-score

\textit{z}-score
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With MathTime Professional 2 fonts from [PCTeX](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html), complete or lite version, reading the [guide](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/guide2.pdf) to pag. 7, you can use in math-mode the "swash" `z`, putting into `\usepackage[.....,lite]{mtpro2}` the option `zswash`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[zswash,lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
$z$
\end{document}
```

This is the relative output.

[image]